# Batch programming an inventory

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a text based game in Notepad++. I have a working shop in it and am attempting to make an inventory. To do so, I put in a script like this:

```
if %bat% equ true echo 1) Bat
```

Now, after that, if they press one, I am trying to change the `%current%` to "Bat". I tried this and it didn't work:

```
If %input3% equ 1 set %current%=Bat
```

I thought this would display the word "Bat" where it is displaying what `%current%` is (it starts as "fist")

Instead, it just displays the name as "0" and not "Bat". I am also trying to set `%damage%` to 9 by doing:

```
if %current% equ Bat set %damage%=9
```

But this did not work. Overall, I want to change `%current%` to "Bat" and am also trying to set `%damage%` to 9.

Comment: Aahhh... I didn't catch that mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `set` syntax is wrong. It's `set variable=value`, not `set %variable%=value`:

```
set current=Bat
```

`%variable%` is used to retrieve the value of an variable:

```
echo %current%
if %current%==Bat set damage=9
```

(note `==` and `equ` are equivalent)

Comment: `==` and `equ` are not exactly equivalent: `if 7==07 echo Equal` will not return `Equal`, but `if 7 equ 07 echo Equal` will, because `==` denotes a pure string comparison, but `equ` converts both expressions to numbers first. (Note that `07` is interpreted as octal number, and `0x7` would be interpreted as hexadecimal number, although not documented in `help if`; this behaviour is similar to the `set /A` command -- see `help set` for details...) However, if you enclose both expressions in double-quotes, `equ` performs a pure string comparison too...

Comment: @aschipfl you are right. I should have added "in your case (string comparison)"